# How is the properly way to use Quarkus profile in application.properties?

Tags: quarkus

I have this application.properties:

```
security.key.reader=myservice-apikey-${quarkus.profile}-reader
```

And quarkus.profile always set to "prod":

```
security.key.reader=myservice-apikey-prod-reader
```

The documentation says programmatically the profile has to be retrieved using `ProfileManager.getActiveProfile()`, but there isn't any information about how we can use profiles in the properties.

A possible solution is:

```
%dev.security.key.reader=myservice-apikey-dev-reader
%test.security.key.reader=myservice-apikey-test-reader
%prod.security.key.reader=myservice-apikey-prod-reader
```

I would like to find another option because I have many keys for each environment.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `And quarkus.profile always set to "prod"`. The profile is depending on how you start your application and the value will be prod, test or dev. Therefore why can't you use
`security.key.reader=myservice-apikey-${quarkus.profile}-reader`?

Comment: @JanMartiška is right. This is from Quarkus Guides :
There are two ways to set a custom profile, either via the quarkus.profile system property or the QUARKUS_PROFILE environment variable. If both are set the system property takes precedence. Note that it is not necessary to define the names of these profiles anywhere, all that is necessary is to create a config property with the profile name, and then set the current profile to that name. For example if I want a staging profile with a different HTTP port I can add the following to

Comment: I remember someone explaing that quarkus.profile is not a standard config property. I'm not sure it can be used inside your application.properties itself.
So the correct way is to duplicate the property for each profile and prefix it by `%` followed by the name of the profile, for example `%dev.security.key.reader=myservice-apikey-dev-reader`.

Comment: Thanks all of you for helping. I did what @loicmathieu suggested.